# Calling all Symfony Coders: New-B's EventDispatcher quietly fails

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm pretty stuck here. I'm trying to include an EventDispatcher in an Ajax Action but it just quietly fails. I'm pretty new to symfony and am currently working on customizations of the "VImp" CMS (http://vimp.com/) which is based on symfony 1.1.6.
In `/apps/xx/modules/xx/actions/base/BaseXxActions.php` there's this:

```
public function executeAjax {  
    switch($this->getVar('action')) {  
        case 'something':  
            sfContext::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->notify(
              new sfEvent(
                $this,
                'activity',
                array(
                  'action' => 'user.something.save',
                  'user' => sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getUser(),
                  'something'=>$something
                )
              )
            );  
        break;    
    }  
}
```

Now this just quietly does nothing. Nothing in the server or the symfony logs. I pretty much just copy/pasted the line from a couple of lines earlier and it doesnT seem to matter which parameters I use.
Can someone help me here? Where and how do I get specific info on why this fails?
Thanks,
thomas
(I also can't get syntax highlighting to work ...)

Comment: Well, what exactly fails and where? Also, what does the title `Calling all Symfony Coders: New-B's` mean exactly? :) You want to phone all symfony codes and collecting their telephone numbers? :)))

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call is actually fired? See apache logs also, to see if some request arrives after launching your ajax call

Comment: Have you tried debugging your ajax request? Xdebug + firefox's plugin (easyXdebug) are remarkable.

Comment: Hello, yeah the Ajax call is fired. It does what it's supposed to (which is more than dispatch the event but I left that out ...) As to what fails: The notify() *should* write something in the activity table of my DB but it doesn't. But there's no telling why it doesn't ... I'll try Xdebug, thanks Dziamid!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ever faces the same problem ... I finally found my solution:

```
class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration 
{  
    public function configure()  
    {  
       // Register our listener  
       $this->dispatcher->connect('user.something.save', array('myClass', 'itsMethod'));
    }  
}
```

This tells the event dispatcher what to do in case the event is fired.